What kind of bird is כרום?
In Brachos 6b it says

מאי כרום? כי אתא רב דימי אמר עוף אחד יש בברכי הים וכרום שמו. וכיון שחמה זורחת מתהפך לכמה גוונין
What is kerum referred to by Rabbi Yoḥanan and Rabbi Elazar? When Rav Dimi came to Babylonia from Eretz Yisrael he said: There is a bird in the cities by the sea called kerum and when the sun rises, the bird changes several colors. Similarly, one who becomes dependent upon others blushes in embarrassment.

Is this Krum bird extinct or is this bird still around? If so, what is the Krum?

A possibility is that it refers to a bird known as the "Cinnyris osea" (Palestine Sunbird).
On the Daf-Yomi website, Rav Steinsaltz's commentary is quoted:

In Rabbi Steinsaltz's commentary on Berakhot, two African species of starlings with a variety of physical colors are suggested: the splendid starling (Spreo superbus) and the magnificent glossy starling (Lamprocolius splendidus), which resemble the Palestine Sunbird found in our region.

"Krum" might refer to the Greek word χρώμα and means "colour", which might refer to a colourful bird.

χρῶμα (chroma) being the ancestor of many words in European languages, including the element Chromium i.e כרום

According to Sefer haArukh al haSh"S with additions by R'Binyamin Musafia and edited by R'Meir Meizlish according to the order of Sh"S, Krum is a singing bird-of-paradise from the family of Paradisaeidae. Specifically, Raggiana bird-of-paradise has characteristically blushing color as noted by the gemara.

This seems difficult on ornithological/historical grounds. Most birds of paradise are restricted to New Guinea, and none naturally occur west than the Moluccas; skins/specimens were certainly traded farther afield, but my impression is that they essentially weren’t known outside Southeast Asia until relatively recent times.  The OED’s earliest mention in English is from 1568, and I think that’s close to when knowledge of them reached Europe; I seem to remember reading that specimens were brought as gifts to Indian courts a little earlier, but not much.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I do not argue, just quoting the book. I agree that further research is needed. The other answer suggests a bird which has brown and green colors, not color of a blushing face.

Could this be a misunderstanding? Aruch HaShalem (by Kohut, not the Aruch) says, on the authority of Brüll and Lewysohn that כרום is the green pigeon (Asia-Africa). Then he says Lewysohn also suggested "Paradiesvogel, Sonnenvogel" apparently as if two names for one bird by which he could mean Leiothrix (as near as India).

@ba The Lewysohn's comment is very unclear.  Sonnenvogel is the Palestine Sunbird from the other post if we translate from German. Paradiesvogel is the bird of Paradise from New Guinea from this post! The wikipedia does not seem to give either description of Sunbird or Bird of Paradise to Leiothrix.

@YDJ According to this website: Sonnenvogel is Leiothrix argentauris. According to Wiktionary: Rotschnabel-Sonnenvogel is Leiothrix lutea. Both confirmed on their respective German Wikipedia pages. German Wikipedia gives no indication of Sonnenvogel being a name for Cinnyris osea.

@ba I guess the quoted answers given here did not consult ornitologists but translated directly. Certainly, please write the answer, and I will give +1. Despite this, the Leiothrix lutea is native to southern China and the Himalayas. Leiothrix argentauris is native to Northern and eastern India, Bhutan, northern Burma and southern China. Either one is far from Israel and not by the sea.

I'm not sure how plausible it is overall, I just wanted to see whether the Aruch on Shas book might have meant something other than what you understood at first (which as @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine noted seems hardly possible)
